# Update data from the Mobile App to the Android Auto app

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

I was following this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/car-app-library-fundamentals#0) Here as you can see there's a common Repository to share between the Mobile App and the Android Auto app (that runs in the DHU). I was wondering how to update a e.g a string in the Auto app from the Mobile app ? I have tried to use `sharedprefs` but as these two apps has different `context` I didn't succeed. Also `content provider` didn't work because two apps lives in two different hardware I guess. What are my other options ? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: not really. it seems the android auto documentation is limited still..

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firebase's real-time database or another cloud service.

With real-time services you will change each variable easily

Comment: Hi, did you test it yourself ? because these two are not simple android apps and they live on two different system. Even to send a notification from mobile app to the auto app you need to use CarAppExtender..

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question in wrong way. Best regards

Comment: for this the car app needs to be connected as well. my concern more was the communication from the mobile app to car app when they are connected by wire without needing the internet

Answer (score -2):

If you have two separate apps running in different contexts (e.g., a mobile app and an Android Auto app), sharing data between them can be challenging due to the sandboxed nature of Android apps for security reasons. However, you can consider a few approaches to achieve communication or data sharing between these apps:

1. Using a Shared Database or File
2. Content Provider with Permissions
3. Using Broadcasts or Intents
4. Custom Networking or API
5. Shared Preferences (with Content Provider or File)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy